# Adding raw files to .gitignore

Tags: c++, git, github, ubuntu-18.04, gitignore

I created a git repository folder which contains all of my C++ code. When I compile the code with `g++ -g filename.cpp -o filename -lgraph` in my *Ubuntu 18.04*, it creates a `filename` file without extension. I want git to stop tracking all these created files while I do `git add .` and track the rest. What should I add to the *.gitignore* file so that these files are ignored?

Comment: `filename`? Or why not put the output not into the repository or give all output a name, so you can ignore it: `filename.tmpout` then add `*.tmpout`

Comment: @RoQuOTriX So, should I add an extension *.tmpout* to the output files? Will the output file still run the same?

Comment: @deekeh Why can't you just add `filename` to .gitignore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+without+dots

Comment: @user253751 All files will have different names. I just used ```filename``` as a placeholder to the file name. I want want git to ignore all the output files at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use an build Folder outside the source Folder.

But if you really need the output executable to be in the source Folder you can add following to `.gitignore`:

```
*
!*.cpp
!*.h
```

If you do so, git ignores all files which are not `cpp` or `c`-Files

- `*` git ignores all files
- `*.cpp` but does not ignore cpp files
- `*.h` but does not ignore h files

Depending on other files you have in your source Folder you have to exclude them too.

But it is better to have an dedicated build folder.

Edit:
You can even have the build folder inside your source folder and exclude everything inside this folder.

```
build/*
```

Make sure the `build` folder exists

```
mkdir build
```

and modify your call to `g++`

```
g++ -g filename.cpp -o build/filename -lgraph
```